# when use conv and deconv, the out put shape does not math(The input image's weight is odd)

Tags: python, pytorch, conv-neural-network, deconvolution, encoder-decoder

such as the input shape=[1,64,12,60,33]

when i use

```
nn.Conv3d(in_channels=128, out_channels=64, kernel_size=(3, 3, 3), stride=2, padding=1)
```

the out put shape =[1,64,6,30,17]

after that i want to let the output return to [1,64,12,60,33]

but when i use

```
 nn.ConvTranspose3d(in_channels=128, out_channels=64, kernel_size=(3, 3, 3), stride=2, padding=1,output_padding=1)
```

the out put become to [1, 64, 12, 60, 34] that is not i want.

how can i fixed this problem? i mean i want the nextwork doesn't matter the input's shape(of course i don't use dense layer, just conv and deconv)

for example:

```
input = torch.randn((1,64,12,60,33))
C3d=torch.nn.Conv3d(64,64,kernel_size=(3,3,3),stride=2 ,padding=1)
output_conv = C3d(input)#shape==[1,64,6,30,17]
de_C3d = torch.nn.ConvTranspose3d(64,64,(3,3,3),stride=2,padding=1)
output_deconv=de_C3d(out_conv) #shape = [1,64,11,59,33]
```

i just want the output_deconv.shape equal to input

Comment: Your first conv3d should have `in_channels=64`.

Comment: excuse ， it's a clerical error ;what i care is the last dim.

Comment: Did you change `in_channels` or `out_channels`? Can you please give a concrete example with some dummy data (just use `torch.randn` or something) to show people what problem you are facing?

Comment: i just add a example in my problem, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If you're dealing with tensors of arbitrary shapes, this can be difficult. If they're fixed you can add ad hoc fixes which should solve your problem. One way is to utilise the fact that you can pass tuples to the arguments `padding` and `output_padding`, which will work in your case:

```
input = torch.randn((1,64,12,60,33))
C3d=torch.nn.Conv3d(64,64,kernel_size=(3,3,3),stride=2 ,padding=1)
output_conv = C3d(input) #shape==[1,64,6,30,17]
de_C3d = torch.nn.ConvTranspose3d(64,64,(3,3,3),stride=2,padding=1,output_padding=(1,1,0))
output_de=de_C3d(out_conv) #shape = [1,64,12,60,33]
```

You could also pad and then crop, which is commonly done in UNet architectures:

```
de_C3d = torch.nn.ConvTranspose3d(64,64,(3,3,3),stride=2,padding=0)
output_deconv=de_C3d(out_conv) #shape = [1,64,13,61,35]
output_deconv = output_deconv[:,:,:input.shape[2],:input.shape[3],:input.shape[4]]
```

I guess one way to fix this is to add different padding to the inputs depending on whether they're odd or even:

```
de_C3d = torch.nn.ConvTranspose3d(64,64,(3,3,3),stride=2,padding=1,
          output_padding=tuple([(i+1)%2 for i in input.shape[2:]]))
output_deconv=de_C3d(out_conv) #shape = [1,64,12,60,33]
```

Comment: thanks, you are a such good person. excuse, it comes too late